# Is it possible to change a document builtin styles using c# interop.word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I understand that one could simply use a template; But I am looking at the possibility of changing say the font size of Heading 1 and color as well.

I have tried something like this

```
Style style = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Styles.Add("Heading 1");
style.Font.Name = "Verdana";
style.Font.Size = 36;
```

The above denotes an error that heading 1 is a preserved name.

I have also found one suggesting something like this:

```
ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1").AutomaticallyUpdate = True
ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1").Font.Name = "Verdana"
```

However in the above; Styles is not a method to take parameters. 
I have looked into some members of Styles class and it seems to have [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.style_members.aspx) to change the styles like AutomaticallyUpdate; but can't figure out how to work it out.

So it is possible to change a builtin style to a different font or so using c# interop.word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ...

In C#

```
Style style = ActiveDocument.Styles["Heading 1"];
style.Font.Name = "Segoe UI";
style.Font.Size = 48;
```

In VBA

```
Dim stl As Style
Set stl = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
stl.Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
stl.Font.Size = 48
```

Now if you type something in the Heading 1 style it will be in Segoe UI with the size of 48.